# Why polyglot does not return the un-transliterated text back?

Tags: python, nlp, transliteration, polyglot, indic

```
eg = 'bajra bechna बाजरा बेचना'
fin=''
text = Text(eg)

for x in text.transliterate("en"):
    fin = fin + ' ' + str(x)


print(fin)  

output:
बाजरा बेचना
```

I am loosing the initial English text in the output. How can I get all of it in the output?

Comment: So you need ` बाजरा बेचना बाजरा बेचना` twice??

Comment: Yess @Ajay , cuz its just an example I have data where the text has bilingual letters

Comment: https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Detection.html#language-detection

Comment: There's languagge detector in `polyglot`

Comment: I've a problem installing `pycld2` which is useful in language detection..else i could have helped with an answer

Comment: So when I tried using that for this example ''bajra bechna बाजरा बेचना'' it gives hindi but some other time it gives English, its not consistent.

Comment: did you download the models also???https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Transliteration.html#downloading-necessary-models

Comment: `downloader.list(show_packages=False)`

Comment: Yess I did install the models, you can try pycld2 installation by downloading .whl file for your python version.

Comment: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: I'm on ubuntu ..